# Store account information in VS to SQL Database

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I'm working on a Text-based RPG game using C++ in Visual Studio, where I want player account details and information to sit on a database. At the moment, I'm working on a very simple log in screen that allows a user to either log in to a previously created account, or create a new one.

I have set up a local SQL database (which currently doesn't have an tables), which is connected to my Visual Studio project, but I'm quite new to the database side of stuff and want to know how I can go about doing the following:

1. Allow a user to set up and create a user account, which then sends this information and stores the info to the database (just username and password for now)
2. Allow the user to log back in to their account
3. Throw the correct prompt if a user attempts to log in to an account that doesn't exist on the database

Covering this will be a great way for me to understand how each account will work independently off of each other, which should enable me to start setting independent player stats to each account.

Is someone maybe able to help me get a better understanding of how this would work and how I can go about achieving this?

If I haven't given enough specific information please let me know and I'll edit this question.

Comment: Games are meant to be distributed, and mysql ( needs to sit in each clients) is quite heavy for that. For game, try something light like sqlite3, which can be embedded into your game software directly.

Comment: Hi @seccpur, I'll have a look at this, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a SQL script in your project to create the database and table(s). You can add auser_id field if you have other tables reference the user. password should be hashed, not plain text.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS game_db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
  user_name varchar(64) not null PRIMARY KEY
  password varchar(255) not null
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

Comment: Hi @PeterHe, thank you for this answer. Could you possibly show me an example of how this script would be called in a C++ program to send the credentials to a database? Would really appreciate this!

Comment: You don't need to call it from C++. The script file can be deploy using mysql client tool mysql, something like:     mysql -hserver -uuser -p yourDB < ScriptFile